# Testing angular directive with relative template path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've a directive like below:

```
var directiveFunction = function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '../medical/app/components/address/address.template.html',
            controller: controllerFunction,

            scope: {
                address: '='
            }
        }
 };
```

When I run my `test-case` against this directive it fails. But when I change my `templateUrl` to below it passes:

```
templateUrl:'components/address/address.template.html',
```

Why is it not taking from `relative` root path? My application structure follows like below:

```
medical
-- app
   -- components
      --address-card
         --address.template.html
```

The reason i am using it with `relative path from root`, the same `directive` is consumed by other modules.

Comment: And.. what's the question about? Root path not allowed, that's why failed

Comment: Why not use absolute path? We don't know what path of page is where this gets used. Inspect request in browser dev tools network for more clues

Comment: Why is this path failing? templateUrl: '../medical/app/components/address/address.template.html', and why is this passing             templateUrl: 'components/address/address.template.html',

Comment: why? because they point to different places

Comment: @charlietfl: they point to the same places, but the directive is being called in multiple modules.. in that case you need to ensure the templateUrl forms from base

Comment: again...why can't you use absolute path? Doesn't necessarily have to include the protoocl or domain to be absolute...a simple leading `/` makes it absolute starting at root

Comment: What is your 'test case'? Does the question mean that the same directive works for you in production? How exactly is it used in both cases? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve